# How to redraw exactly the same polygon that was drawn by the user (more than 4 vertices)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My project involves allowing user to draw a polygon on Google Maps, and at a later even retrieve that shape. For this I'm storing the polygon path in my database, and querying it at a later stage to Draw it for the user again. This works when I have simple polygons (like Triangles, or squares), but complicated ones are seldom the same polygon as was drawn.

I am getting the coordinates of path through: 
`var polyArray = selectedShape.getPath().getArray();`
I store these values in my database.

To draw, I'm using google.maps.Polygon() :

```
var redrawnPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: polygonCoords
      });
```

As you can see the images of polygons are not the same as drawn, which makes sense because the vertices stored by getPath() can produce more than one polygon. How can I make sure that the original polygon is the one drawn? Shouldn't getPath() add more vertices automatically? Should I do them manually? How?

Drawn by the user:
[image]

Redrawn using google.maps.Polygon()
[image]

Comment: How are you storing the vertices in your database?  Are you maintaining the order? 
 What does the data for your example polygon look like when you retrieve it from the database?  What is the contents of `polygonCoords`? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the corrupted polygon.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The key point was 'Order', thanks for sharing that. Retaining the order of the coordinates of Polygon solved the issue and I can now recreate exactly the same polygon as before.

Comment: The Polygon class has 2 methods `getPath()` and `getPaths()`. The first one retrieves only the first Polygon path. Just saying as you mentioned "complicated" polygons...

Comment: Thank you @MrUpsidow. I already looked into those, as I understand good example for getPaths would be with space inside (hole, or holes in the polygon). My case was simple issue of order :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @geocodezip in comment above, the root cause of the issue was that I was not retaining the order of the coordinates in my database.

Saving and fetching coordinates in the same order fixed the issue and I can now recreate exactly the same polygon as was drawn.